# How to convert from a HID Usage ID to a Virtual Key Code in Windows OS?

Tags: windows, winapi, keyboard, key, hid

Is there a way to convert a USB HID Usage ID to a Virtual Key code in Windows OS?

for example,

HID Usage ID 0x04  --->  Virtual Key is 0x41  (this is key A)

HID Usage ID 0x91  --->  Virtual Key is 0xE9  (this is a OEM specific key)

HID Usage ID 0x87  --->  Virtual Key is 0xC1  (this is a Reserved key code)

...

I just found a [virtual keys code table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx),
but I can't find a translation table or a way to translate it efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to translate between HID Usage IDs and virtual key codes. The translation is performed by the device driver.

The Usage IDs for keyboards are published on http://usb.org in the [HID Usage Tables](https://usb.org/sites/default/files/hut1_22.pdf) specification (Chapter 10 "Keyboard/Keypad Page (0x07)").

Answer (score 0):

Window API [PS/2 I8042 scan codes](https://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller) (set 1) for keyboard input for historical reasons. Scan codes for USB/Bluetooth HID keyboards are produced by Windows Keyboard HID client driver from HID usages internally with a call to [HidP_TranslateUsagesToI8042ScanCodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidpi/nf-hidpi-hidp_translateusagestoi8042scancodes) (one-way `hid usage -> scan code` table is baked inside `Hidparse.lib` that is usually not used by user code. You can find this table [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#scan-codes)).

Here is code to do keyboard HID usage to scan code conversion:

```cpp
static uint16_t HIDUsageToScanCode(uint8_t usage)
{
    uint8_t index = usage;

    // 256 bytes
    static const uint8_t usage2scan[] =
    {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1e, 0x30, 0x2e, 0x20, 0x12, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x17, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26,
        0x32, 0x31, 0x18, 0x19, 0x10, 0x13, 0x1f, 0x14, 0x16, 0x2f, 0x11, 0x2d, 0x15, 0x2c, 0x02, 0x03,
        0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x1c, 0x01, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x39, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x1a,
        0x1b, 0x2b, 0x2b, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f, 0x40,
        0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x57, 0x58, 0xb7, 0x46, 0xc5, 0xd2, 0xc7, 0xc9, 0xd3, 0xcf, 0xd1, 0xcd,
        0xcb, 0xd0, 0xc8, 0x45, 0xb5, 0x37, 0x4a, 0x4e, 0x9c, 0x4f, 0x50, 0x51, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x47,
        0x48, 0x49, 0x52, 0x53, 0x56, 0xdd, 0xde, 0x59, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x6b,
        0x6c, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x76, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x73, 0x70, 0x7d, 0x79, 0x7b, 0x5c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x72, 0x71, 0x78, 0x77, 0x76, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x1d, 0x2a, 0x38, 0xdb, 0x9d, 0x36, 0xb8, 0xdc, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    };

    return ((usage2scan[index] & 0x80) ? 0xe000 : 0) | (usage2scan[index] & 0x7f);
}
```

After you have a scan code you can convert scancode to VK code by means of active keyboard layout (mapping that is embedded in keyboard layout dll file - for example US English is `kbdus.dll`). And this VK code you're receive in `WM_KEYDOWN` etc message.

You can do this `scan code <-> VK code` conversion with a call to [MapVirtualKeyEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeyexw) API with `MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX (3)` flag set.